# delphi typinfo SetPropValue

Tags: delphi, reflection

Hi I have a problem with this code:

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ActnList, StdCtrls, Buttons, MSObjCtrls, StrUtils;
type
  Data = class(TObject)
    FName : string;
    FValue : string;
  private
  public
  published
    property Name : string read FName write FName;
    property Value : string read FValue write FValue;
  end;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtResult : TMSObjectText;
    btnGo : TMSBitBtn;
    ActionList1 : TActionList;
    acGo : TAction;
    procedure acGoExecute(Sender : TObject);
  private
    procedure Split(Delimiter, S : string; Strings : TStrings);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1                                 : TForm1;

implementation

uses TypInfo;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Split(Delimiter, S : string; Strings : TStrings);
var
  P, OldP                               : integer;
  Token                                 : string;
begin
  if (Strings = nil) or (Length(S) = 0) or (Length(Delimiter) = 0) then
    exit;
  P := Pos(Delimiter, S);
  OldP := 1;
  while P > 0 do
  begin
    Token := Copy(S, OldP, P - OldP);
    Strings.Add(Token);

    OldP := P + 1;
    P := PosEx(Delimiter, S, OldP);
  end;
  if P = 0 then
    Strings.Add(Copy(S, OldP, Length(S)));
end;

procedure TForm1.acGoExecute(Sender : TObject);
var
  Lst, tmpLst                           : TStringList;
  i                                     : Integer;
  Obj                                   : Data;
  str                                   : string;
begin
  str := 'Name=Jordan Borisov;Value=man';
  Lst := TStringList.Create;
  tmpLst := TStringList.Create;
  Split(';', str, Lst);
  Obj := Data.Create;
  for i := 0 to Lst.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Split('=', Lst[i], tmpLst);
    try
      SetPropValue(Obj, tmpLst[0], tmpLst[1]);
    except
      ShowMessage(Format('Invalid  property name %s', [tmpLst[0]]));
    end;

    tmpLst.Clear;
  end;
  edtResult.Text := 'Name[' + Obj.Name + '],Value[' + Obj.Value + ']';
end;

end.
```

Could someone tell me where is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you tell us what's not working. Does it not compile? Does it not do what you want? What's the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot.
The problem is that in the method SetPropValue I try to set a new value to the property Name in the class Data but an Exception it's raise everytime with the text : The Property Name does not exists.

Comment: Lst and tmpLst needs to be free'd in acGoExecute.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it's working properly on my end (I only replaced the MSObjCtrl by regular ones). So, nothing wrong with the code per se. Some project options maybe?  Maybe having the exact text of the exception would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTTI is generated for classes compiled with [`{$TYPEINFO ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_%28Delphi%29) (or `{$M+}`) directive. `TObject` is not one of them; it starts at `TPersistent`. So either derive your class from TPersistent, or use the `{$M+}` directive in your code (before the declaration of your class).

Comment: Though `TObject` is not compiled with {$M+}, the compiler automatically adds {$M+} when it sees `published` properties in `TObject` descendant (with warning). At least Delphi 2009 does so.

Comment: @Serg: it's still the same in XE/XE2. This is the [warning](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W1055_Published_caused_RTTI_(%24M%2B)_to_be_added_to_type_'%25s'_(Delphi)). Thanks for the info.